# Prove that $\left(\sum^n_{k=1}x_k\right)\left(\sum^n_{k=1}y_k\right)\geq n^2$

Tags: inequality, summation, induction, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

> If $x_1,...,x_n$ are positive real numbers and if $y_k=1/x_k$, prove that $$\left(\sum^n_{k=1}x_k\right)\left(\sum^n_{k=1}y_k\right)\geq n^2.$$

I've been learning induction, and I've come across this problem that I really can't even break down and begin to think about. I've been told it has something to do with Cauchy-Schwarz, but I cannot figure out how to apply it. I would appreciate help figuring out how to go about and formulate this proof. Thanks!

Comment: Does it help to call $x_k$ by the name of $a_k^2$?

Comment: Cauchy-Schwarz inequality has sum of $a_k^2$ and sum of $b_k^2$ terms multiplied together. Can you guess that?

Comment: One way to begin on a problem like this is to take a small $n$ and see what's going on.  For $n=2$ the inequality is $$(a+b)\left(\frac{1}{a} + \frac{1}{b}\right) \geq 4$$.  Can you show that?

Comment: HM-AM inequality.

Comment: This follows from the Arithmetic Mean - Harmonic Mean inequality

Comment: See also this answer http://math.stackexchange.com/a/194349/269624

Comment: Just use the Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality with $x_i=\sqrt{a_i}$ and $y_i=\frac{1}{\sqrt{a_i}}$.

Comment: There is an interesting general case here: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/768630/269624

Comment: See also: [Is it true that $\forall n \in \Bbb{N} : (\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_{i} ) (\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{a_{i}} ) \ge n^2$ , if all $a_{i}$ are positive?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3081320)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are couple of ways to prove this. One way is via AM-GM, i.e., we have
$$\sum_{k=1}^n x_k \geq n \sqrt[n]{x_1 x_2 \ldots x_n}$$
and
$$\sum_{k=1}^n \dfrac1{x_k} \geq n \sqrt[n]{\dfrac1{x_1 x_2 \ldots x_n}}$$
Multiplying the two, we get what we want.

Another way is consider the vectors
$$\left(\sqrt{x_1},\sqrt{x_2}, \ldots, \sqrt{x_n} \right) \text{ and }\left(\dfrac1{\sqrt{x_1}},\dfrac1{\sqrt{x_2}}, \ldots, \dfrac1{\sqrt{x_n}} \right)$$ and apply Cauchy-Schwarz to get what you want.

Comment: In the first proof you are actually proving the AM-HM inequality ;)

Comment: Very helpful. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 5):

You can in fact prove it by induction on $n$. For the induction step observe that

$$\begin{align*}
\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}x_k\right)\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\frac1{x_k}\right)&=\left(\sum_{k=1}^nx_k+x_{n+1}\right)\left(\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{x_k}+\frac1{x_{n+1}}\right)\\
&=\left(\sum_{k=1}^nx_k\right)\left(\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{x_k}\right)+x_{n+1}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{x_k}+\frac1{x_{n+1}}\sum_{k=1}^nx_k+1\\
&\ge n^2+1+x_{n+1}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{x_k}+\frac1{x_{n+1}}\sum_{k=1}^nx_k\;;
\end{align*}$$

$(n+1)^2=n^2+2n+1$, so to finish the step, it suffices to show that

$$x_{n+1}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{x_k}+\frac1{x_{n+1}}\sum_{k=1}^nx_k\ge 2n\;.$$

For $k=1,\ldots,n$ let $u_k=\dfrac{x_k}{x_{n+1}}$; then

$$x_{n+1}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{x_k}+\frac1{x_{n+1}}\sum_{k=1}^nx_k=\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\frac1{u_k}+u_k\right)\;,$$

and it’s not hard to show that if $u>0$, then $\dfrac1u+u\ge 2$, either by showing that $f(u)=\frac1u+u$ on the positive reals has a minimum at $u=1$, or by observing that for $u>0$ we have $f(u)\ge 2$ if and only if $u^2+1\ge 2u$ and showing that this inequality is always true.

Comment: I will just mention that a similar proof can also be found here: [Proof by induction for tricky double summation: $(\sum_{k=1}^n x_k)\cdot(\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{x_k})\ge{n^2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1506405#1506474).

Answer (score 5):

The function 
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$$
Is convex on $(0,\infty)$, so for $a_1,\ldots,a_n>0$ we have
$$\frac{n}{a_1+\cdots+a_n}\leq\frac{1}{na_1}+\cdots+\frac{1}{na_n}.$$
Rearranging, we obtain the result.

Answer (score 3):

$$\left(\sum_{k=1}^n {\sqrt{x_k}}^2\right)\left(\sum_{k=1}^n {\sqrt{x_k^{-1}}}^2\right)
\ge \left(\sum_{k=1}^n {\sqrt{x_k}}\sqrt{x_k^{-1}}\right)^2 = n^2$$

Answer (score 3):

We let $x_{i+n}=x_i$ for $i\in\{1,2\dots n\}$ .What you have is $\sum_\limits{i=1}^n (\frac{x_1}{x_{1+i}}+\frac{x_2}{x_{2+i}}+\dots \frac{x_n}{x_{n+i}}).$

By the rearrangement inequality each of these summands is greater than $1+1+\dots +1=n$

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}
\sum_{k = 1}^{n}\left(\sqrt{x_{k}\,} + {\mu \over \sqrt{x_{k}\,}}\right)^{2} &\geq 0\,,
\qquad
\mu \in {\mathbb R}
\\[3mm]
\left(\sum_{k = 1}^{n}{1 \over x_{k}}\right)\mu^{2}
+
2n\mu
+
\left(\sum_{k = 1}^{n}x_{k}\right) &\geq 0
\\
\left(2n\right)^{2}
-
4\left(\sum_{k = 1}^{n}{1 \over x_{k}}\right)\left(\sum_{k = 1}^{n}x_{k}\right)
&
\leq 0
\end{align}

$$
\begin{array}{|c|}\hline\\
\color{#ff0000}{\large\quad%
\sum_{k = 1}^{n}x_{k}\sum_{k = 1}^{n}{1 \over x_{k}}
\color{#000000}{\ \geq\ }
n^{2}
\quad}
\\ \\ \hline
\end{array}
$$

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Cauchy-Schwarz inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality#Rn_.28n-dimensional_Euclidean_space.29) with $u_i = \sqrt{x_i}$ and $v_i=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x_i}}$.

Answer (score 0):

By [Chebyshev's Inequality](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Chebyshev%27s_Inequality) we have that

$$\left(\sum_{k=1}^n x_k\right)\cdot\left(\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{x_k}\right) \geq n\sum_{k=1}^n x_k \frac{1}{x_k}=n^2$$

and therefore

$$\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n x_k\right)\cdot\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{x_k}\right) \geq 1$$