# Proof by induction for tricky double summation: $(\sum_{k=1}^n x_k)\cdot(\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{x_k})\ge{n^2}$

Tags: inequality, summation, induction

let $x_1....x_n$ be positive integers. Prove by induction the following for natural numbers n:

$(\sum_{k=1}^n x_k)\cdot(\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{x_k})\ge{n^2}$

Hint: for all positive integers a,b: $\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{a}\ge2$

Comment: I highly suspect that OP is supposed to prove that given expression is $\geq n^2$.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry I missed a part out! I shall fix now

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I have fixed it now

Comment: @Wojowu yes you are right

Answer (score 3):

The inductive step should be

$$\left(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\right)\left(\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{x_i}\right)$$
$$=\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} x_i + x_n\right)\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{x_i} + \frac{1}{x_n}\right)$$
$$=\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} x_i\right)\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{x_i}\right) + \frac{1}{x_n}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} x_i\right) + x_n\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{x_i}\right) + 1$$
Now
$$\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} x_i\right)\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{x_i}\right) \geq (n-1)^2$$
and

$$\frac{1}{x_n}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} x_i\right) + x_n\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{x_i}\right) = \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\left(\frac{x_i}{x_n} + \frac{x_n}{x_i}\right) \geq 2(n-1)$$
so that
$$\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} x_i\right)\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{x_i}\right) + \frac{1}{x_n}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} x_i\right) + x_n\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{x_i}\right) + 1 \geq (n-1)^2 + 2(n-1) + 1 = ((n-1) + 1)^2 = n^2$$

Comment: I will mention that a similar proof can be found in this answer: [Proof that $\left(\sum^n_{k=1}x_k\right)\left(\sum^n_{k=1}y_k\right)\geq n^2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/504240#504267).