# Simple inequality involving product of sums

Tags: inequality

Suppose we have a sequence of numbers such that $0<x_1 \leq x_2 \leq x_3 \leq...\leq x_n$. Would it be possible to show that $(\sum \frac{1}{x_i})(\sum x_i) \geq n^2$?

Comment: Yes, you may want to read about rearrangement inequality

Comment: Could you, please, elaborate a little? I am not sure I see how this inequality can be applied in my situation. Thank you!

Comment: While $x_{i}$ is increasing, $\frac{1}{x_{i}}$ is decreasing. Another way to show this is to use AM - HM inequality.

Comment: This has been asked and answered many times. See for example https://math.stackexchange.com/q/504240/42969 (found [with Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24(%5Csum%20%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bx_i%7D)(%5Csum%20x_i)%20%5Cgeq%20n%5E2%24)) and the [linked threads](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/504240).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality](https://brilliant.org/wiki/cauchy-schwarz-inequality/) on the sequences $\left\{\dfrac1{\sqrt{x_1}},\dots,\dfrac1{\sqrt{x_n}}\right\}$ and $\{\sqrt{x_1},\dots,\sqrt{x_n}\}$ to have

$$ \left( \sum_{i=1}^n \left( \dfrac1{\sqrt{x_i}} \right)^2 \right) \left( \sum_{i=1}^n \sqrt{x_i}^2 \right) \ge \left(\sum_{i=1}^n \dfrac1{\sqrt{x_i}}\sqrt{x_i}\right)^2=\left(\sum_{i=1}^n 1\right)^2=n^2$$

---

There are a number of ways to show this, of course, for instance using the AM-HM inequality on the $n$ positive numbers $x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n$ as $$\text{A.M. of the $n$ numbers}=\dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i}n \ge \dfrac{n}{\sum_{i=1}^n \frac1{x_i}}=\text{H.M. of the $n$ numbers}$$

---

To clarify the comments, you can also use a certain generalization of the Rearrangement inequality called the [Chebyshev Inequality](https://www.imomath.com/index.php?options=598&lmm=0) on the *oppositely-sorted* sequences $$x_n \ge x_{n-1} \ge \dots \ge x_1\\
\frac1{x_n} \le \frac1{x_{n-1}} \le \dots \le \frac1{x_1}$$ to get the desired result as well. In fact, the Chebyshev inequality can be proved using the [Rearrangement Inequality](https://www.imomath.com/index.php?options=598&lmm=0) (which is how Rearrangement inequality can be used to prove this without knowing Chebyshev's inequality, i.e. you would basically be doing the proof of Chebyshev's inequality given in the link above, if you scroll down in it a bit.)

Comment: Do leave a comment on an answer when you downvote it, it would help me attract lesser downvotes in the future. :)